# Get the return value from executable jar launched from MFC(c++) Application

Tags: c++, shell, mfc, executable-jar

I am developing a project where I am launching a jar file. I want a return value from that jar file. I have surfed on net and got a clue that `System.exit(n);` can be read from the program from where am launching it. I also came to know that I can read it using shell script. But I am completely unaware of what how to write a shell script. I am new to MFC(C++). The code used to launch the jar file is as follows.

```
void CDropboxSync::OnBnClickedDbxPcToCloud()
{
    STARTUPINFOW        siStartupInfo;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION piProcessInfo;

    memset(&siStartupInfo, 0, sizeof(siStartupInfo));
    memset(&piProcessInfo, 0, sizeof(piProcessInfo)); 
    SetCursor(LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_WAIT));
    if (CreateProcess(m_csJrePath, TEXT(" -jar DbxUpldDwnld.jar u"), NULL, NULL, false, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, NULL, (LPSTARTUPINFOA)&siStartupInfo, &piProcessInfo) == false) {
        AfxMessageBox(_T("Please install Java Runtime Environment(JRE) on your PC\n Or JRE not found on given path in INI File."), MB_ICONERROR);
        CloseHandle(piProcessInfo.hProcess);
        CloseHandle(piProcessInfo.hThread);
        return;
    }


    CloseHandle(piProcessInfo.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(piProcessInfo.hThread);
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
}
```

So from here how can I get the return value from the JAR file. All the experts out their please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should mix shell scripts and MFC. You launched the process from your program and you can call:

```
DWORD exitStatus;
CreateProcess(...)
...
WaitForSingleObject(piProcessInfo.hProcess, INFINITE);
GetExitCodeProcess(piProcessInfo.hProcess, &exitStatus);
```

to obtain the exit code of a process you launched. Make sure to call this before you call `CloseHandle(piProcessInfo.hProcess);`

It it true though that maybe you'll find it more convenient to wrap the process you are launching in a shell script, but that doesn't make any difference to your MFC code.

Comment: Thanks mate, Let me try it.

Comment: I noticed you are not waiting for the process to finish, you can wait on its handle - see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the updated code I couldn't get the Exit status for the previous code.